# What is wrong with this json string?Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got 'STRING'

Tags: json

```
    {
  "data": {
    "domains": {
"domain sample_domain_1": { 
        "name": "sample_domain_1"
      }
"domain sample_domain_11": { 
        "name": "sample_domain_11"
      }
"domain sample_domain2_11": { 
        "name": "sample_domain2_11",
        "mode": "current"
  }
"domain sample_domain2_yw": { 
        "name": "sample_domain2_yw",
        "mode": "invalid"
      }
"domain sample_domain2_y1": { 
        "name": "sample_domain2_y1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

getting the error
Error: Parse error on line 6:
...e_domain_1"          }           "domain sample_domai...
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got 'STRING'

Comment: https://jsonlint.com

Comment: Missing commas - commas are required between *all* fields, of any type. Please use existing validator tools: jsonlint makes this error 'extra clear', although the giveaway from above is the arrow "^" pointing to the middle of `..domain_1" } "domain sample..` .. depending on the output of a tool you may have to align the "^" lines externally.

Comment: You need commas after each `}` In the list of domains

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add commas to your json data

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "domains":{  
         "domain sample_domain_1":{  
            "name":"sample_domain_1"
         },
         "domain sample_domain_11":{  
            "name":"sample_domain_11"
         },
         "domain sample_domain2_11":{  
            "name":"sample_domain2_11",
            "mode":"current"
         },
         "domain sample_domain2_yw":{  
            "name":"sample_domain2_yw",
            "mode":"invalid"
         },
         "domain sample_domain2_y1":{  
            "name":"sample_domain2_y1"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed commas at the end of items.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, aligning up the arrow will point to the precise location.

Here is the formatted output from jsonlint.org:

```
Error: Parse error on line 6:
..._1"              }               "domain sample_domai...
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got 'STRING'
```

(The output is aligned in a *monospaced font*, 8 space tabs here.)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "**,**" at the end of every object in "domains". It should be

```
{
    "data": {
        "domains": {
            "domain sample_domain_1": {
                "name": "sample_domain_1"
            },
            "domain sample_domain_11": {
                "name": "sample_domain_11"
            },
            "domain sample_domain2_11": {
                "name": "sample_domain2_11",
                "mode": "current"
            },
            "domain sample_domain2_yw": {
                "name": "sample_domain2_yw",
                "mode": "invalid"
            },
            "domain sample_domain2_y1": {
                "name": "sample_domain2_y1"
            }
        }
    }
   }
```